# How set value for variable if I know its string name?

Tags: c#, variables

I have class

```
public class Rule
{
    public int IdRule { get;set;}
    public string RuleName { get; set; }
}
```

I have List of Hashtable with values. Have key "idRule", "ruleName".
Example

```
List<Hashtable> list = new Hashtable();
list["idRule"] = 1;
list["ruleName"] = "ddd";
```

I have function:

```
private static List<T> Equaler<T>(T newRule)
{
   var hashTableList = Sql.Table(NameTable.Rules); //Get table from mssql database
   var list = new List<T>();
   var fields = typeof (T).GetFields();

   foreach (var hashtable in hashTableList)
   {
       var ormRow = newRule;
       foreach (var field in fields)
       {
            ???what write this???
            // i need something like 
            //ormRow.SetValueInField(field, hashtable[field.Name])

       }
       list.Add(ormRow);
   }
   return list;
}
```

Call this function:

```
var rules = Equaler<Rule>(new Rule())
```

Question: How set value for variable if I know its string name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use reflection to do this.

```
string value = hashtable[field];
PropertyInfo property = typeof(Rule).GetProperty(field);
property.SetValue(ormRow, value, null);
```

Since you know the type is Rule, you can use `typeof(Rule)` to get the Type object. But if you did not know the type at compile time you can also use `obj.GetType()` to get the Type object as well. There is also a complementary property `PropertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null)` which allows you to retreive the value with only the 'string' name of the property.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5dd1f1.aspx

Comment: Why not `typeof(Rule).GetProperty(field)` instead?

Comment: @OscarMederos Fixed and noted the difference between getting type object at compile time and runtime.

Comment: I mean in your example. You're still calling `typeof(Rule).GetType()` instead of just `typeof(Rule)`.